# Why do individuals vary in the number of SNPs for a given gene ( e.g. FOXO3A )?

Tags: genetics, homework, population-genetics, snp

Individual #1, sequenced by 23andMe and then inputed into Promethease for SNP data has the following SNP output:

1) rs1935949(C;T)
2) rs2802292(G;T)
3) rs13217795(C;T)
4) rs13220810(C;T)
5) rs2764264(C;T)
6) rs9400239(C;T)
7) rs2153960(C;T)
8) rs2802288(A;G)

Thus individual #1 has eight reported SNPs.

Individual 2 also is sequenced by 23andMe and then inputed into Promethease for SNP data has the following SNP output:

1) rs2802292(T;T)
2) rs2764264(T;T)

Therefore individual #1 has eight reported SNPs for the FOXO3A gene and individual #2 has only two reported SNPs.

Since SNPs represent single nucleotide polymorphisms in the sequence, why does individual #2 only have two SNPs recorded rather than all eight?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! We encourage you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). For ["homework"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) questions, you are **required** to show your attempt to answer the question and to use the "homework" tag. ——— Please take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 

Comment: Why are there more brown-eyed people than blue-eyed people in Britain? Consider. It is the gene that exhibits polymorphism in the population, not the genome of an individual. The statement that someone has so many SNPs is incorrect. He has so many occurrences of the less common variant of a site that exhibits single nucleotide polymorphism. So your question is really why do individuals differ. I imagine you can suggest reasons for that.

Comment: Thank you for the welcome:I think my confusion is based on visualizing SNPs as single base pair substitution in the gene:

I thought SNPs can vary by basepair but not in total number - here 8 vs 2.  In the example rs2802292 is possessed by both individuals but with #1 carrying (G;T), and #2 carrying ( T;T) SNPs for rs2802292 which makes sense.

But, some rs #’s are only in person #1, such as rs1935949 (C;T).   So person #2 can have (C;C), (T;C), (C;T), or (T;T).  However #2 has no listing at all for rs1935949.  How can it be that no SNP of any type is present at location rs1935949? Thanks!

Comment: So, if I'm understanding correctly your question is why you aren't getting SNP information for all the variable positions? That seems like something to ask 23andMe about. IIRC they don't actually sequence DNA and so, due to the technology they use, I suspect that for some locations they may not obtain information.

Comment: Perhaps they don’t report an SNP if your base is the same as their reference genome.

Comment: Yes tyersome, my question is why we aren't getting SNP information for all the variable positions ( eight variable positions for individual #1 from the original example whereas only two from individual #2).  Your hypothesis does not appear to fit the situation however since individual #1 which has more variations reported also used 23andMe at the same time, so this does not appear to be a 23andMe issue?  Other ideas?

Canadianer - I am not clear this is the case since for other alleles ( besides FOXO3A we are discussing), 23andMe has reproted all (4) possible allele combinations at each SNP.

Comment: Not necessarily — for example, failures to detect information at a SNP could be due to an individual having an unusual sequence that the 23andMe technology can't "see" ...

Comment: Interesting point tyersome.  My understanding is that SNPs by definition correspond to only single nuceleotide substitutions as opposed to larger sequences ( ie those affecting >=1% of population).   Given that is the case it seems what the technology would only need to detect single nucleotide combination variants - (C;C), (T;C), (C;T), and (T;T) at that SNP locus.  The gene chip can detect any of those diploid combinations, so why would it be unable to detect which one of those 4 possibilities is present at that locus.

Comment: What do you think would happen if there was small insertion immediately adjacent to a SNP? How about a deletion of the region containing a SNP? I suspect uncharacterized or rare polymorphisms nearby might also interfere with binding to the chip. What happens if they expect C or T and you have G? I also don't think you can rule out technical problems at any level (e.g. a damaged/defective patch on the chip, dust in the detector, or software errors ...).

Comment: They have been sequenced several times via multiple companies & whole exome, so it sounds like it is on of the former suggestions you made in your last post.  As of 2015 it looks like there were at least 15 reported FOXO3A SNPs reported: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4326903/   ...... It seems that having a deletion or non C/T nucleotide is far more likely to lead to reduced function than increased function ( being a rarity it is less likely selected for)......How unusual is it then for individual #1 to have only 8 and individual #2 to have only two of thoese 15 FOXO3A SNPs?